# How to insert a new line inside a directive template in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

Hi I know this is an easy question how can you insert a new line in a directive template? I have a long template. and it is hard for me to scan through horizontally. I want to have it in a new line. However angular doesn't want.

```
app.directive('broadcasted', function(){
return{
    restrict: 'EAC',
    // NEW LINE  THE TEMPLATE NOT JUST IN A SINGLE LINE
    template: '<div class="alert alert-success col-md-6" ng-repeat="x in bcards"><strong class="broadcast-text" ><% x.q_number %> - <% x.teller_id %></strong></div>',
    link: function($scope){
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using <br/> ?

Comment: why not to load a template file if you want it to be readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
app.directive('broadcasted', function(){
return{
    restrict: 'EAC',
    // NEW LINE  THE TEMPLATE NOT JUST IN A SINGLE LINE
    template: '<div class="alert alert-success col-md-6" ng-repeat="x in bcards">' + 
              '<strong class="broadcast-text" >' + 
              '<% x.q_number %> - <% x.teller_id %></strong></div>',
    link: function($scope){
    }
};
```

There's also another way described here: [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: Thabks!! That is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it is to put template in seperate HTML file and use `templateUrl`

```
app.directive('broadcasted', function(){
return{
    restrict: 'EAC',
    // NEW LINE  THE TEMPLATE NOT JUST IN A SINGLE LINE
    templateUrl: 'mytempalte.html',
    link: function($scope){
    }
};
```

mytemplate.html

```
<div class="alert alert-success col-md-6" ng-repeat="x in bcards">
   <strong class="broadcast-text" >
              <% x.q_number %> - <% x.teller_id %>
   </strong>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 while this is not exactly what the question asked, this approach is cleaner than concatenating strings in JS source code.

Comment: @igorraush thanks :) . IT's better to guide the OP in right direction. I know i can give answer in terms of  string concat with '+' but it will not run for long if template is very long it's better to keep it in seperate HTML :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use escape character `\`

```
app.directive('broadcasted', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'EAC',
    template: '<div class="alert alert-success col-md-6" ng-repeat="x in bcards"> \
               <strong class="broadcast-text" ><% x.q_number %> - <% x.teller_id %></strong> \
               </div>',
    link: function($scope){
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to not concatenate with the `+` sign:

```
app.directive('broadcasted', function(){
return{
    restrict: 'EAC',
    // NEW LINE  THE TEMPLATE NOT JUST IN A SINGLE LINE
    template: '<div class="alert alert-success col-md-6" ng-repeat="x in bcards">' + 
                   '<strong class="broadcast-text" ><% x.q_number %> - <% x.teller_id %></strong>' + 
              '</div>',
    link: function($scope){
    }
};
```